# PHP cron errormessage

Tags: php, runtime-error

I get these errors:

```
/home/nordic/www/Nordiceliteversiontwobeta/phpcron/_cron_minute.php: line 1: ?php: No such      file or directory
/home/nordic/www/Nordiceliteversiontwobeta/phpcron/_cron_minute.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `{'
/home/nordic/www/Nordiceliteversiontwobeta/phpcron/_cron_minute.php: line 2: `if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != "/phpcron/_cron_minute"){'
```

my code is:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != "/phpcron/_cron_minute"){
```

what went wrong here? i had the same code in a prew script but it dosent work here.

also the path is right, the _cron_minute.php file is in: 
/www/Nordiceliteversiontwobeta/phpcron

and  /home/nordic is right aswell.

it were working on one other file that had:

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != "/_cron_day"){
```

Comment: Have you read the error messages, and attempted to analyze what they might mean in your environment?

Comment: your not calling the file correctly. the cron line should be `... php file.php ...`

Answer (score 0):

Add `#!/usr/bin/php` (or the PHP executable path, you can use `which php` to know which is) ad the first line (before the `<?php`).